# How do I draw a border around a UIImageView contained within a UICollectionViewCell on select?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell subclass that contains a UIImageView. When a given cell is selected, I'd like to add a fixed-width border around the image (i.e. extending from the image view, not within it). Can anyone recommend a good approach?

Incidentally, I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was enlarging the UIImageView (adding the width of the margins), then redrawing the UIImage twice (once with a black border, once with a colored border). I then toggled between imageView.image and imageView.highlightedImage when the cell is selected. I.e. imageView.highlighted = cell.selected

It requires more processing up-front, since each original UIImage is drawn out twice, but if the resulting images are cached (and the originals small) then it's not a big deal.